# Construct regex pattern to identify only seperate words in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the term `e_learning` and I want to see what are terms that includes `e_learning` in `mylist`

```
mylist = ['e_learning_environment', 'machine_learning', 'student_e_learning_platform']
```

I should only get `e_learning_environment` and `student_e_learning_platform` as the output.

My current code is as follows.

```
for item in mylist:
   if 'e_learning' in 'machine_learning':
     print('yes')
```

However when I use `in` in python I also get `machine_learning`. Can I avoid it using regex? Please help me!

Comment: Something like `(:?\b|_)e_learning(:?|_)` could work.  I feel like there's a more clever solution using lookaheads/lookbehinds

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Nah, that's good enough. Just use `re.search` and test its truthiness in a list comp.

Comment: `if '_e_learning' in mystring or 'e_learning_' in mystring:`

Comment: @JohnGordon That works for this, but turns up false positives for a lot of other random cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` with a lookbehind

```
import re
myrootword = 'e_learning' #target search variable
mylist = ['e_learning_environment', 'machine_learning', 'student_e_learning_platform']
new_list = [i for i in mylist if re.findall('(?<=^){}|(?<=\s){}|(?<=_){}'.format(*([myrootword]*3)), i)]
```

Output:

```
['e_learning_environment', 'student_e_learning_platform']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. if I want to give the string such as `e_learning` from a variable named as `myrootword` how can I change this code? i.e `myrootword = 'e_learning'` :)

Comment: @JCena please see my recent edit. I added the variable `myrootword` to store the desired search variable and utilized string formatting to insert the search query in the regular expression.